# .Net logging tool which can change configuration dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I need a logging tool for. Net which can change configuration at runtime. What I want to do is the following:

- application starts and logging should start too
- some data is processed, a certain event occures
- a new logger and a new logging sink is created (a database which does not exist at program start)

log4net works fine for me, as long as I use XML for configuration, but the API for in-code configuration is not very nice and not very well documented. Can anybody recommend an alternative tool, which fits the above usecase?

cheers,
Achim

Comment: Free tools only or commercial tools are also an option?

Comment: You want to be able to change the configuration during runtime from within the application using code? This is an odd model. As you already said, log4net allows dynamic configuration: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html#Dynamic%20Configuration.

Comment: I was not aware the log4net is able to do so, so I will stick to log4net. Usually the model might be odd, but in that case it makes a lot of sense to add an additional logger after some setup code has been executed, because the additional target is not know before. Could you write an answer which I could accept? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Application Block has a nice fluent interface for configuration in code (since 5.0 or 4.1 i cant remember right now)
http://entlib.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This logging framework should suit your needs: [The Object Guy's Logging Framework](http://dotnetlog.theobjectguy.com)